# WD Elements external HDD doesn't mount

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I'm attempting to mount a WD Elements 1 TB drive on Linux, however it does not work. The drive is only visible through gparted. When I reformat the drive while on Linux, partitions work no matter what - fat, ntfs, ext it all mounts fine.

However, after one reboot it's impossible to mount it. This happens on all my Linux installs, while the drive works on all Windows installations I tried it with.

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10.

EDIT: Unmounting/unpowering before unplugging the device is what I was doing, and the drive still always appears the same after a reboot - in the "Disks" application, without any partitions (although gparted sees them).

Comment: @user68186 I added the information. Unmounting before unplugging does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known defect with WD Elements drives.  They ship them with a corrupt format since it claims the disk is slightly larger than it actually appears to be.  You will need to repartition the drive to correct WD's error, and you should complain loudly to WD so maybe they will stop shipping broken drives.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned, it does not work even after reformatting. I tried formatting the drive as half ntfs half ext2 (ideal setup I was trying), I tried to make a new mbr and such, but in the end the drive was still not recognized after a reboot.